# Does model binding work via query string in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, query-string, model-binding

Does model binding work via query string as well ?

If I have a get request like :

```
GET /Country/CheckName?Country.Name=abc&Country.Id=0 HTTP/1.1
```

Would the following method in CountryController have its oCountry argument containing Id and Name properties with values from the query string ?

```
public ViewResult CheckCountryName(Country oCountry)
{
     //some code
     return View(oCountry);
}
```

For some reason I am getting Id as 0 and Name as null in oCountry object. What is missing ?

Comment: Yes but for primitive types like string and int. Not for your case But query string is ugly

Comment: how should I modify my method to make it work (get the values from query string) ?

Comment: @DanHunex I also think querystring parameters are ugly, but how else would you perform a GET http operation without it?

Comment: @DanHunex also if this is intended to be used in a search page, how could the user save the page with the filters they applied to share with someone else, or to save in favorites bar and look again later?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Yes, the model binding supports binding from the query string. However the same model binding rules apply here also: the property names/expressions should match in your request and in your model.

So if you have a `Name` property then you need the have a `Name` key in the query string. If you write `Country.Name` the model binding first look for a property called `Country` and then a `Name` property on that country object.

So you don't need the `Country` prefix for you property names, so your request should look like this:

```
/Country/CheckName?Name=abc&Id=1 HTTP/1.1
```

Or if you cannot change the request you can specify the prefix for your action parameter with the `BindAttribute`:

```
public ViewResult CheckCountryName([Bind(Prefix="Country")]Country oCountry)
{
     //some code
     return View(oCountry);
}
```

Comment: Attributes are amazing, the kind of capability they provide are out of box. Thanks @nemesv
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.bindattribute%28v=vs.108%29.aspx