# MVC navigate back to page with same model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session, tempdata

I've built a Search Page with 5 properties to filter on.
When a user clicks on one of the results the detail page is loaded.
Now I want to provide a "Back" button so the user can go back to the Search Page with the original filter.

I was thinking about using TempData to store the filter model.
Tempdata is stored in session for only one call so the session won't be bloated after a while.

Is there a better sollution or do you guys have some suggestions?
Let me know!

**Edit:**
The search page will make use of ajax calls to page, sort or filter the data.
So all this data will need to be stored if I want to navigate back from the detail page.
Is TempData the best way?

Answer (score 2):

Why not to use query-string for this? E.g. search request is submitted using `<form />` element with `method` attribute set to "get". In this case you can easily restore the form state by just reading from the query-string, the code will be much simpler. Visitors also can easily bookmark the page and return to search results later.

View:

```
@model SearchResultSet;

<form method="get" action="/search">
    <input type="text" name="q" value="@Request.QueryString["q"]" />
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>

@if (Model.Total > 0)
{
    <ul>
        @foreach (var result in Model.Results)
        {
            <li>...</li>
        }
    </ul>
}
```

Model & controller:

```
public class SearchResultSet
{
    public IList<SearchResult> Results { get; set; }
    public long Total { get; set; }
} 

public class SearchController : Controller
{  
    public ActionResult Index(string q = "")
    {
        return View(GetModel(q));
    }

    private SearchResultSet GetModel(string searchQuery)
    {
        // Get search results
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am planning to use ajax calls for the paging, sorting and filtering on the Search page. The website will be used as an internal web app so bookmarking won't be needed.

Comment: @Beejee You can use [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) and still leverage the query-string (because it's very transparent what's going on and not error-prone comparing to one-time session-based storage). As an alternative, you can try [jQuery BBQ](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/) in conjunction with managing state via hashbang. The above solution also makes it much easier to write unit tests for your application.

Comment: The user will be able to sort on multiple properties.
So i will have X filter inputs. How are you going to put all that in a query string? Normally i always bind to a viewmodel when using more than 2 properties.

Comment: I didn't know that a querystring could be bound to a model like explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17329342/does-model-binding-work-via-query-string-in-asp-net-mvc).
This could come in handy yeah. How do you plan on providing the url to the next controller/action to use it for the 'Back' button?

Since I will use ajax calls on the search page.
History API won't contain the filter url/querystring.

Comment: @Beejee You could make your model serializable to query-string like it's demonstrated [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6848296/how-do-i-serialize-an-object-into-query-string-format). Overriding `ToString` method for this could be quite convenient.

Answer (score 2):

Well, TempData retains value for one call, but you can retain the TempData value using `TempData.Keep()` until your Session expires.

```
TempData["YourKey"] = "SomeValue";
TempData.Keep("YourKey");
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Still not sure if this is the best solution.

Comment: To retain values across controllers and across various pages, `TempData` is the one you are looking for.