# Binding Querystring parameters in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, query-string

Is there an equivalent way to bind querystring parameters in an MVC Controller to FromUri, which it seems is only used in MVC API?

I have 2 pages that can have from 0 to 7 querystring parameters, depending on filters that the user selects. I am trying to find a clean effective way to manage the querystring parameters from the controller without having a bunch of if statements. The parameters are basically the same for each page so creating a queryParameter class that both pages can access would be ideal.

It's really easy in an API controller and I would like to do something similar.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Rhonda

Edit.

Say I have the following class:

```
public class QueryStringParams : IEnumerable
{
    public string Page { get; set; }
    public string Top { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }
    public string Size { get; set; }
    public string Width { get; set; }
    public string Price { get; set; }
    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        yield return this.Page;
        yield return this.Top;
        yield return this.Color;
        yield return this.Size;
        yield return this.Width;
        yield return this.Price;
    }
}
```

In In my controller(s) I would like to have something like this:

public async Task Index(string pathAlias, [Bind(Prefix = "QueryStringParams")]QueryStringParams queryParams)

Similar to being able to do this in an API method.

public async Task Get(string pathAlias, [FromUri]QueryStringParams queryParams)

Then reference the querystring parameters like:
var pageNumber = queryParams.Page;

The querystring would look something like this:

http://localhost:12330/br/womens-dresses-shop?page=2&Top=10&color=red

It may or may not have all of the parameters set at any one time.

Is that more clear?

Comment: Maybe it helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17329342/does-model-binding-work-via-query-string-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: The model binding for query string parameters automatically happens in asp.net MVC. You need to be more clear on what you want to achieve exactly.

Comment: Let's start by showing us what your controller action looks like, and the query string that you are using.

Comment: I updated the original post including some code snippets and a better description of what I am trying to do.

Comment: @Rhonda - it is still unclear what you intend to *do* with the query string parameters. Your current class will work fine as a view model (see the link that Filipe Oriani provided). So you have the values in a class. Now what? It seems like that should be sufficient.

Comment: This is an eCommerce site.  The pages I am working on are search and browse results.  The customers can filter and page through the results.  The query string parameters are filter values so when the page loads the filter values are taken from the parameters and used to build the Fast query that gets the products to display.  

Currently when I put a break point in the code and execute it, queryParams is always null, even though there is a querystring in the url I am debugging with.

Answer (score 0):

While not 100% ideal, this seems to work.

public async Task Index(string pathAlias, [Bind(Include = "Page, Color")]BrowseQueryParams queryParams)

Rhonda

Comment: If I want to access all of the parmeters I can just do this:

public async Task Index(string pathAlias, BrowseQueryParams queryParams)

Which I think is what someone was trying to say in one of the comments.  I was trying to over complicate things.